# Can't change permissions in windows 10, stuck on read only

Tags: windows-10, permissions

I'm having some permission issues with Windows 10. Files are stuck on read-only, tried to change permissions according to this article:

[Document folders marked read-only after upgrade to Windows 10](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/document-folders-marked-read-only-after-upgrade-to/4f00d3fe-82b0-4e6d-a92a-f81751aa6f51?auth=1&ranMID=24542&ranEAID=je6NUbpObpQ&ranSiteID=je6NUbpObpQ-OXLHt2bPaPuGBUWaJ8XCTQ&tduid=(2eb33a43bea3715747818a3657b2eea3)(256380)(2459594)(je6NUbpObpQ-OXLHt2bPaPuGBUWaJ8XCTQ)())

But it's not working, and now even worse after following these steps, all accounts show "Full Control" and nothing can be changed anymore...but still stuck on read-only...;([image]

Comment: Show permissions and owner